# PHP: If file called X exists, then show its content

Tags: php

I want to create pages depending on file name on my server. I want to make a "note system" using files. I use Parsedown to write .txt in Markdown, in directory "documents/notes". In the main folder (home) there's a file called "notes.php" that I use to display my posts (not on this page, I want to show conent individualy by its name). So, all I want to do is: script which knows what files I have in "documents/notes". And if I type "notes.php?note=X", where X is the file name, then it shows the content of this post. I don't want to edit "notes.php" to make each post readable, I want to create an universal code where all I have to do is create a .txt file. So, if I type "notes.php?note=X" then the script looks for file X, and if it exists - it shows the content.

Hope it's understable to you. :)

Comment: PHP is more than capable of doing that sort of thing. Get busy writing code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this code in your `note.php`:

```
$filename = 'documents/notes/' . $_GET["x"];
if (file_exists($filename) && !is_dir($filename)) {
    echo file_get_contents($filename);
}
```